# Populating d3.tip with correct data

Tags: d3.js, charts

I'm adding a tooltip to a d3.js chart using d3.tip.v0.6.3.js.

It seems to work fine on charts that only have 2 columns of data for example:

```
category    count
Asia    17
Eastern Europe  16
Africa  15
```

But when I am using the same code for a stacked bar chart, I get "undefined". I know I'm missing something obvious. The data for the chart looks like this:

```
Category,Statistics,Psychology,Programming,Mental health,Aboriginal education
Other,1,3,1,4,2
Lifelong learner,20,39,36,44,48
```

In the chart that works I simply put d.count and the count data is returned to the tip.

But in the new chart I want to return the data that is NOT "Category" as the mouse moves over the rectangles of the bar chart.

```
var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) { return "<span>" + d.name + "</span>" + " " + /*varHere*/ } );
```

I have a version of it here: [embedded view on Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/5Vq9TL1dxE7a1tiCPZVy/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to hack your data-binding a bit to include the "value" of the bar:

```
state.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { 
    return d.ages.map(function(d0){ //<-- add in the relevant value to ages array
      d0.value = d[d0.name];
      return d0;
    });
})
.enter().append("rect")
...
```

Then the `.html` call becomes:

```
.html(function(d) { return "<span>" + d.name + "</span>" + " " + d.value } );
```

Updated Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/8HGS3MhkOGNFJEHUknsP?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks Mark. I appreciate you looking at this. I'll see if I can modify the data bind as you suggest.

Comment: Works like a charm!